# Yii2 GridView Pagination + Search Filter

Tags: yii2

trying to enable both pagination and search filters in a gridview. I understand I'm overwriting dataProvider in the following code, but I am not sure how I could otherwise do it. The problem, of course, is that currently if I change the page or do a filter search, the pagination disappears.

```
public function actionLibrary()
{
    $query = FileEntry::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ],
    ]);

    $searchModel = new FileEntrySearch();

    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
    {
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->get());

    }

    return $this->render('library', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    ]);    
}
```

Comment: just add `pagination` params in the `search()` method of the `FileEntrySearch` model, why are you initializing the `dataProvider` if you are overriding it

Comment: I agree with @MuhammadOmerAslam, add `dataProvider` initialize in your `FileEntrySearch()` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);`

This assumes, that your `$searchModel` is already an instance of an ActiveDataProvider, which I assume you defined in your FileEntrySearch model. So your action could look something like this:

```php
public function actionLibrary()
{
    $searchModel = new FileEntrySearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('library', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    ]);    
}
```

and your FileEntrySearch:

```php
class FileEntrySearch extends FileEntry
{
    // [...] rules, scenarios etc.

    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = FileEntry::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query
        ]);

        // you can add sorting here

        $this->load($params);

        // you can define your filters here

        return $dataProvider; // this will become your $searchModel
    }
}
```

No dataProvider overriding this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can change pagination configuration after creating data provider:

```
public function actionLibrary() {
    $searchModel = new FileEntrySearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->get());
    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 10;

    return $this->render('library', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    ]);    
}
```